# After executiing query, why it gives table not exist error ?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute following query:

```
Insert into pligg_links_temp
select * 
from pligg_links 
WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000;
```

but I get this error:

```
#1146 - Table 'chris123_pligg.pligg_links_temp' doesn't exist   when trying to execute query to create table
```

the table does not exist but it should be created in the process or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying records from a table to another table can be done in two ways.

1. insert by selection into an existing table.
2. create and insert by selection into a new table, created from
   selected table fields structure.

Your error stacktrace says that the table `pligg_links_temp` doesn't exist.
Then your statement to `create and insert` table data is incorrect.

To copy records from an existing table to a new table, you require to use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) syntax.

Use the following sample:

```
create table pligg_links_temp -- as /* as is optional */  
  select * from pligg_links WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000;
```

If the target table already exists, you can use [`INSERT ... SELECT Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) statement to copy records.

```
insert into pligg_links_temp  
  select * from pligg_links WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000;
```

Comment: first option: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[as] select * from pligg_links WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000' at line 1

Comment: @Chriswede No. Either use `as` or don't use it. Square braces are used symbolic for optional. It is self explanatory.

Comment: create table pligg_links_temp []
select * from pligg_links WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000; : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[] select * from pligg_links WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000' at line 1

Comment: select * from pligg_links WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000; works perfectly

Comment: sorry now I understand just exclude [] sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

The query should be

```
CREATE TABLE pligg_links_temp AS SELECT * FROM pligg_links WHERE link_id > 0 and link_id < 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldnt create it for you.
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html clearly says the table must exist.